# конфиг nginx отловить запрос

Tags: nginx

есть такой запрос на сервер

```
: 220.133.170.135 [18/Jul/2020:05:07:32 +0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 150 "-" "-"
```

как его отловить и выдать нужный ответ? Как пытался:
1.

```
# запрет доступа если в запросе нет имени сервера или оно любое корявое
server {
listen                      %ip%:%httpport% default_server;
listen                      %ip%:%httpsport% ssl http2;
server_name                 "~.*";

return                      444;
}
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

2. 

```
if ($host = '') {
return 444;
}
```

Поясню, в запросе пустой $host, такие запросы нужно обработать по 444 ответу, точнее все запросы, не соответствующие доменам или алиасам.

Comment: Убрать из всех конфигов `default_server`

Comment: убрал, не помогло